# SSIS Package Upgrade

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS Solution with 4 packages created in SSIS 2005. When I opened the solution in SSIS 2008, it went for SSIS Upgrade wizard. But the upgradation had failed. The error messages are shown as follows :

1. Error 0xc001405f:: Failed to decrypt an encrypted XML node because the password was not specified or not correct. Package load will attempt to continue without the encrypted information.
2. Error 0xc001f429:Package Upgrade: The loading of the package Package1.dtsx has failed
3. Error 0xc0016016: : Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.

What is the correct step for upgradation from 2005 to 2008 ?

Comment: You might want to try to open the packages in 2005 and change the way sensitive data is saved ( don't use userkey or password ) - and then just re-enter any sensitive data after the upgrade has completed.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS packages developed in VS 2005 are not supported in VS 2008. VS 2008 need SSIS 2008. For more details check below link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/a4c788cb-8461-4066-96a4-894dcb8de332/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but if the packages were moved from a different machine, maybe you should check protection level at the original machine http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;904800